# Why does the first call to readline() slow down all subsequent calls to fnmatch()?

Tags: c++, c, linux, readline, glob

The following program illustrates the issue:

Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -O3 -std=c++0x
LDFLAGS = -lreadline

test: test.o
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $< $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

test.o: test.cpp Makefile
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <fnmatch.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

static double time()
{
    timespec    ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
    return ts.tv_sec + (1e-9 * (double)ts.tv_nsec);
}


static void time_fnmatch()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        double t = time();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            fnmatch("*.o", "testfile", FNM_PERIOD);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "%f\n", time()-t);
    }
}

int main()
{
    time_fnmatch();

    char *input = readline("> ");
    free(input);

    time_fnmatch();
}
```

Output:

```
0.045371
0.044537
> 
0.185246
0.181607
```

Before calling readline(), the fnmatch calls are about 4x faster. Although
this performance difference is worrying, I'm most interested in finding out
what exactly the readline() call might be doing to the program state that
would have this effect on other library calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a guess: `readline` initialization probably calls `setlocale`.

When a program starts up, it is in the `C` locale; a call to `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` will enable the default locale, and these days, the default locale usually uses UTF-8, in which case many string operations become more complex. (Even just iterating over a string.)

Comment: Replacing readline() with setlocale(LC_ALL, "") has the same effect on runtime - good guess.

Comment: After further research, readline() definitively calls `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, lspec);` with `lspec` from the environment's LANG variable on my system (reference: readline 6.3 source code, nls.c).

Also see this interesting comment in the readline.c source for python:

`/* GNU readline() mistakenly sets the LC_CTYPE locale.
 * This is evil.  Only the user or the app's main() should do this!
 * We must save and restore the locale around the rl_initialize() call.
 */`

Comment: @ajclinto: I agree with the comment in the Python wrapper.